# Firebase Realtime Database: Can't read or write to a node because of a security rule

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have these rules set up for my "chats" node, but my Flutter app can't read or write to it. I double checked that the correct `auth.uid` value is written in the "members" node. Not sure what's going on.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "appName": {    
        "groups": {
          "$groupID": {
            "chats": { /// Properties: uid, username, timestamp, text, type
            /// Users must be a member of the groupID to read and write to the "chats" node
            ".read": "root.child('groups/' + $groupID + '/members/' + auth.uid).exists()",
            ".write": "root.child('groups/' + $groupID + '/members/' + auth.uid).exists() && newData.hasChildren(['uid', 'username', 'timestamp', 'text', 'type'])"
            }
            "members":...
          },
        },
    }       
  }
}
```

**Inserting the data:**

```
  //Save a single message to RTDB
  void saveMessage({required ModelChatData message, required String groupID}) async {
    await globals.userGlobals(); //Required if using globals

    final rtdbGroupChatPath = 'appName/groups/QSsAJCSZqBuzGQo948G1/chats';
    final rtdbGroupChatRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(rtdbGroupChatPath);
    rtdbGroupChatRef.push().set(message.toJson());
  }
```

**Reading:**

```
void getChatListener() async {
    await globals.userGlobals(); //Required if using globals
    final node = 'appName/groups/QSsAJCSZqBuzGQo948G1/chats';

    _groupChatRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(node);

    _chatsSubscription = _groupChatRef.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      dataList = [];

      for (final child in event.snapshot.children) {
        dataList.add(child.value);
      }

      setState(() {
        chats = dataList;
      });

    });
  }
```

**The nodes (I couldn't fit the appName node above groups, but it's there):**

[image]

**The error:**

> Unhandled Exception: [firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

**Current state of the rules (after suggestions in answers/comments):**

```
{ 
    "rules": {  
        "appName": {
            "groups": { 
                "$groupID": {
                    "members": { /// Properties: uid, username, addedTimestamp
                        /// Users must be a member of the groupID to read and write to the "chats" node
                        ".read": "root.child('appName/groups/' + $groupID + '/members/' + auth.uid).exists()",

                        /// Only allow reads from RTDB (except chats). Handle any modifications to it via Firestore triggers/cloud functions
                        ".write": false
                    },
                    "chats": { /// Properties: uid, username, timestamp, text, type
                        /// Users must be a member of the groupID to read and write to the "chats" node
                        ".read": "root.child('appName/groups/' + $groupID + '/members/' + auth.uid).exists()",
                        "$msgID": {
                            ".write": "root.child('appName/groups/' + $groupID + '/members/' + auth.uid).exists() && newData.hasChildren(['uid', 'username', 'timestamp', 'text', 'type'])"
                        }
                        
                    }
                },
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the query that you're using against these rules?

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the code to the question

Comment: We have no way to know what value `globals.groupChatsNode(groupID: widget.groupID);` returns. Does that value include the literals `groups/` part of the path? Otherwise this won't point to `groups/$groupID`, but just `$groupID`, which doesn't seem to exist. Can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded path? If so, can you show the code for that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added the path as a hardcoded string.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the hardcoded string that Puf asked for. Note that the `appName` node was missing in my rules - I've added this, but still getting the same error that the client doesn't have access to the desired data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `.write` rule (`newData.hasChildren(['uid', 'username', 'timestamp', 'text', 'type'])`) you have validates an individual chat message, not the entire `chat` node of a group. That means you have to move it one level deeper into the rules JSON:

```
"chats": {
  "$messageid": {
    ".write": "root.child('appName/groups/' + $groupID + '/members/' + auth.uid).exists() && newData.hasChildren(['uid', 'username', 'timestamp', 'text', 'type'])"
  }
```

Comment: Aw crap yea I missed that. Let me try that and see if it works

Comment: Still not working. I then tried adding `appName/` since it was missing, i.e. `".write": "root.child('appName/groups/..."` but it's still giving the same error

Comment: "still not working" First up, does the explanation I gave in my answer makes sense? Does that explain why your code/rules don't work? And does it make sense how the change I proposed would fix that specific problem? --- There may be other problem in your code/rules, but was definitely one of them.

Comment: Other problem: you seem to have the same problem in the path inside the rules itself, here: `root.child('groups/' + $groupID + '/members/' + auth.uid)`

Comment: Yes, what you mentioned in your answer made sense and it was definitely a problem. I've corrected that in my rules (see the end of the question for the current state of the rules). I also went ahead and added a picture of my database.

Comment: I by now pointed out a second mistake in your rules too, the missing `appName` in the rule itself.  I recommend doing more debugging on the remaining problems yourself, and posting a new question with a better isolated [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you can't get it to work from what I already uncovered so far.